# EF Core - Mapping Many-to-One

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a mapping between the 2 tables using EF Core Data Annotation.

So here's my sample scenario. Let's suppose I have theses classes that consist of following properties

Orders

```
[Key] 
public int OrderId {get;set}
public string OrderNumber {get;set;}
```

OrderStatuses

```
[Key]
public int OrderStatusId {get;set}
public string OrderNumber {get;set;}
public StatusEnum Status {get;set} // Pending, Delivered, Cancel
```

I have this example data:

```
OrderId                 OrderNumber // Order Table
1                       11111
2                       11111
3                       11111
4                       22222

OrderStatusId           OrderNumber         Status
1                       11111               Pending
2                       22222               Pending
```

Basically, I created `OrderStatuses` table that stores the status of the `OrderNumber` but they have no relationship since I have no idea how to make them `Many-to-One` using Data Annotation of Entity Framework Core without using the `key`. I want to achieve this so I can use the `.Include` method in fetching all the info.

The key is, Many Orders but One Status only. I hope somebody helps me.

Comment: Can one order have many OrderStatuses or one order have one OrderStatus only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are wanting `many-to-one` between `Order` and `OrderStatus`, It seems you have configured your model relation wrongly.

So your `OrderStatus` and `Order`   model class should be as follows:

```
public class OrderStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderStatusId { get; set; }
    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }

    public ICollecton<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}

public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public OrderStautsId {get;; set;}

    public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way sir to use Data Annotation instead of fluent api? because I need to follow a project structure. so it should be data annotation

Comment: No! You cannot configure alternate key with data annotations. For more details see the link in my answer.

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy  please let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I'm facing an error in my `update database` command. it says something like, `The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name Orders name AK_Orders_OrderNumber`

Comment: Oh! One order shouldn't not have only status? Or will have many status?

Comment: From my example sir, let's say we have order numbers `111111, 11111,111111` so I want to have them only one status which stores in my status table.

Comment: Then you have yo store the StatusId in Order table, not order numner on status table. Okay I am updating my answer.

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy Please follow my updated answer and also remove the fluent API configuration that you added.

Comment: Thank you sir for the effort and help :)

Comment: Great to hear! Happy coding.